# Проблемы при проектировании многогопоточного приложения

Tags: python, python-2.x, celery

Всем, привет и сразу к делу. 
Есть некоторая задача, пусть будет foo()

```
def foo():
    capture m, use m, leave m, do smth
```

Далее, есть n множеств, содержащие m элементов. Множество является одним из параметров для foo(). Когда задача запускается, она должна найти в заданном ей множестве свободный элемент и захватить его, провести некоторые операции, освободить и продолжить делать некую работу. По идее элементы m полноценные mutex-объекты, практически -- это файлы. За час в брокер насыпается около 30 тысяч задач foo. Реализация через блокировку файлов имела некоторые проблемы: 
Все "воркеры" занялись обработкой задач использую одно множество, т.е. если в нем один элемент, то все простаивают и ждут когда он освободится. В этот же момент в брокере присутствуют задачи для других множеств, у которых есть свободные элементы. Если возвращать задачи в брокер при помощи raise, то в принципе все оказываются при деле, но поскольку очередь с приоритетом, то этот метод не всегда работает. Один раз на файл повесился lock, но не снялся и все "воркеры" повисли в ожидании. Воссоздать ошибку не получилось, но страшновато, если на боевом сервере это произойдет. 
С KazooClient.Semaphore удалось хотя бы не пускать воркеров в множества, у которых заблокированы все элементы, а внутри опять lock файлов. 
Собственно, мне кажется, что задача довольно таки ясна.

Используемые технологии на данный момент:
Django1.11 + celery + RabbitMQ + kazoo?

Теперь, собственно, вопросы: 
1. Можно ли превратить объекты m в объекты типа-mutex и передавать их в задачу, чтобы попробовать внутри найти свободный и отказаться в таком случае от lock'а. Вроде бы в kazoo присутствуют необходимые технологии, но, к сожалению, дедлайн близится и хотелось бы уже работать, а не учиться. 
2. Иногда в очередь может свалиться большая куча задач для одного множества с высоким приоритетом и если я все правильно понял, то все "воркеры" у меня опять повиснут, т.к. будут брать задачу, не находить свободного "m" и падать обратно. Вроде бы решается, если для таких задач создать отдельную корзину, но даже тут они могут начать жонглировать первой десяткой задач.

Если у кого-нибудь идеи, а лучше ссылки на код, который решает мою проблему. Очень уж не хочется самому писать распределителя задач. 
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: О чём вопрос не ясно. Вы тут смешали несколько уровней приложения. Какой-то сленг непонятный: *"полноценные mutex-объекты, практически -- это файлы."* Если уж вы детали  реализации отрывочные начинаете описывать, то можно минимальный пример кода, который иллюстрирует проблему с конкретной реализацией привести (с нуля лучше начать)¶ Причём здесь проектирование не ясно (если вас именно проектирование интересует, то опишите *что* вы хотите чтобы работало (с точки зрения пользователя), какие конкретно у вас требования, какие конкретно проблемы с текущей архитектурой).

Comment: Прошу прощения за сумбур, старался развернуто написать.

Comment: Прошу прощения за сумбур, старался развернуто написать. У менять есть n-папок, в них один или более файлов. При старте воркер получает путь к какой-либо папке. Там он должен найти свободный файл и взять оттуда настройки. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы воркеры как можно меньше простаивали в ожидании файла и исключить возможность одновременного использования. Также, если в корзине лежит 1000 задач для папки А, и 1 для Б, то возникает следующая проблема: все n воркеров копаются в папке A. Заходят, не находят свободного конфига и скидывают задачу обратно в очередь. Нужна балансировка. Спасибо.

Comment: вы снова пытаетесь отрывочные детали реализации описать ("как"), а не "что"¶ Определившись с требованиями, используйте возможности готовой очереди задач (вы упомянули celery), к примеру посмотрите на `-Ofair`, `--scheduler`. Если не хватает возможностей или вообще не подходит, посмотрите какие готовые job schedulers, workload automation системы ближе всего к вашему случае (из разных категорий: Slurm, k8s)

Comment: На сайте есть профиль, у которого есть m-учетных записей. Через одну учетку нельзя делать несколько одновременных действий. Соответственно каждая таска должна искать свободную учетку.  Мда, очень плохо объясняю, если вы предлагаете мне префорки отключить.